# JavaScript setTimeOut function not working

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have the following JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  update_items();
  adjust_size_of_menu();
});

var adjust_size_of_menu = function() {
  // global boolean set in update_items_count();
  if ( !items_updated ) 
  {
     alert("Treatment of update_items() not done yet");
     setTimeOut( function(){ adjust_size_of_menu(); }, 1000);
  }
  // More treatment goes here 
}
```

As you can see, I am setting a variable in the first function. This variable must be `true` before I proceed with the execution of the rest of the instructions in the second function.

The problem here is that the first time I go into `adjust_size_of_menu()`, it shows me the alert, which is fine. After that, it should wait 1 second then re-execute the `adjust_size_of_menu()` from the beginning until the item_updated boolean is `true`, then we continue with the rest of the code.

What is the problem with this code? I've already used the same approach elsewhere and worked just fine.

Comment: It should be `setTimeout()`--you've capitalized it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeOut` is not a built-in function in javascript.  If you've used it elsewhere, it's because you or someone else declared it.  The correct spelling is `setTimeout`.  Note the lowercase "o".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: That was the problem ! The search was not case sensitive and it was showing me the other setTimeout even if i was looking for setTimeOut...

Answer (score 1):

javascript is case sensitive language and it should be setTimeout()